# ROS on Android Phone

Tags: android, robotics

Currently I'm trying to run ROS node on Android Phone to remotely control a robotic. I found that ROS node on Android Phone could publish message to a Topic, but could not subscribe to any topic. Is anyone know the reason?

Thanks,
Liu.

Comment: Are you getting any errors or is it silently failing?

Answer (score 4):

You should search [ROS Answers](http://answers.ros.org/questions/) for your question or others similar that might help you solve your problem. If you don't find a solution, feel free to post the question there. Since ROS Answers is a ROS specific forum, you'll likely get much better support there than here on StackOverflow.

If you do post there, please include as much detail as you can to help with debugging the problem. Any error messages, how you have your network configured, etc would be helpful (and if possible, include links to your source code).